# Update multiple XElements in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<Contacts>
    <Person name="James" id"=1" />
    <Person name="Edward" id"=2" />
</Contacts>
```

I want to do something, so if ID=2, create 10 more Persons and update their ID's and names, this way:

```
if (person.ID == 2)
{
    foreach (var item in duplicatePersons)
    {
        pers.SetAttributeValue("id", item.Key);
        pers.SetAttributeValue("name", item.Value);
        allPersons.Add(pers);
    }
}
```

duplicatePersons is a dictionary that contains all the duplicate persons.

The problem is, that the first iteration of this foreach loop is creating:

```
<Person name="Josh" id"=3" />
```

After the second iteration, it should look like:

```
<Person name="Josh" id"=3" />
<Person name="Jacob" id"=4" />
```

But it looks like:

```
<Person name="Jacob" id"=4" />
<Person name="Jacob" id"=4" />
```

So the 2nd iteration updates both the first and second elements.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set all the attributes to the same object instance `pers`. You should create a new Person object int the loop

```
foreach (var item in duplicatePersons)
{
    Person pers = new Person();
    pers.SetAttributeValue("id", item.Key);
    pers.SetAttributeValue("name", item.Value);
    allPersons.Add(pers);
}
```